# Python: Modifying elements of a list

Tags: python, list

Really basic question, Im taking in a list of say 50 ints.

I need to re number each element

exampleList[4,6,78,21,3,32 etc....]

need to return the list as returnList[0,1,2,3,4,5 etc...]

```
numOfRemaps = len.exampleList
while remap < numOfRemaps
      for item in exampleList:
            if remap != item:
                    item = item + 1

            remap = remap + 1
```

This is the point at which I get lost, can I rewrite the variables back to exampleList, or should I write them to returnedList, and then map it back to exampleList.

Probably a straightforward question, been asked to do a bit of python on the fly, caught me off guard!

Comment: How I interpret this question is that he wants to iterate over a list of ints, change the individual ints based on some logic and wants to put back the ints into the list. He is asking whether he can put the `item` back into the list after modification or should he insert it into another list and assign it to the original list at the end

Comment: item = item + 1 reassigns item, it doesn't change the value in the list

Comment: As @JonClements said it below, `range(len(..))`is the first idea that come to mind ... but I'm not sure we understand correctly the question? Please could you post both your _full_ input data and your expected output.

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified, the list that I am taking in is unknown to me.

Comment: I am simply taking in this list, and reassigning each element as e.g. 0-35, if there are 36 elements in the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the general case, use `enumerate` to get the index and the item. Then you can assign back to the list

```
    for i, item in enumerate(exampleList):
        if remap != item:
                exampleList[i] = item + 1

        remap = remap + 1
```

Comment: Using this answer as the basis, I got exactly what I needed:

Comment: {
exampleList[0,0,0,0,0]
remap = 2

for i, item in enumerate(exampleList):
        if i>1:
                if remap != item:
                        
                        exampleList[i] = remap
                        i+=1
                        remap +=1

print(dLPIDs)
#Expected output [0,0,2,3,4]
}

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do this?

```
print range(len(your_list))
```

Otherwise, use a list-comp:

```
print [i+1 if some_criteria(i) else 0 for i in your_list]
```

Comment: +1 this is how I interpreted it but it didn't make sense to me

Comment: @jamylak yup and it hasn't been clarified exactly what the question is, but... *sighs*

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to Jon Clements answer which you can use if you have every int, you can just use sorted  if you're missing some ints in between.

```
myList = sorted(exampleList)
do_whatever(myList)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
org_list = [4,6,78,21,3,32]
new_list = [item if(item == idx) else item+1 for idx, item in enumerate(org_list)]
```